# Compare two lines from different layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am stuck with a task to compare two line features from 2 different shape files. They don't have any common field so i can't join them. I have source for street names and existing street names in database. My task is to compare which of these names match and find the mismatches.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? I would start with Spatial Join to get the names in the same attribute table

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: All good suggestions/answers. But it is possible that one of your datasets is just more spatially accurate and/or detailed; the other may have better or more complete names. So I would use spatial tools and visual exploration of data and shapes so as to not waste much time matching them if one is clearly better. Then you can just keep the better one and pull some attributes from the other.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to:

1- Create a common field in both layers (ex. Street_Name), fill this field with street names by using field calculaltion.

2- Merge both layers in one (or append)

3- Then dissolve the new layer by choosing (Street_Name) as dissolve field and (Street_Name) as statistics field with statistic type "count"

4- this will generate a new layer and for each street name you will have a field (count), if that field is more than one mean that street is duplicated or triplicated according the number that this field has.

5- than for a deep analysis you can take all features that have just 1 count, transfer to excel and make different analysis to catch the cases then there is just a letter different or just one a space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Spatial Join to join the attribute table of one of the street feature classes to the other. Use Match Option CLOSEST
2. Add a new field to the resulting feature class of type DOUBLE and Field Calculate:

Pre-Logic:

```
def matchname(name1, name2):
    import difflib
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, name1, name2).ratio()
```

And (change to match your field names):

```
matchname( !Streetname1!, !Streetname2!)
```

You will now have a ratio of how well the street names match, 1 = full match

[image]

See: [difflib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects)

Comment: Really like this approach very simple and understandable. The only problem that i still have is that some of the street names are written with capital letters, and the comparison doesn't work properly when it has to compare CAPITAL with Capital. Thanks again.

Comment: ohhh just found how to modify the code ;) tnx

Comment: @KalinVasilev nice! For example make them capitilized: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm . If my answer solved your problem could you accept it with the checkbox?